# WPF - Replacement of Ribbon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ribbon

I have a WPF UI with [Ribbon Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon?view=netframework-4.5) in it. I recently have to switch my UI to old framework .net 3.5 and it seems that Ribbon was introduced in .net 4.5.

How do I switch and get rid of ribbon control ?

What is the best suitable path so that not much source code have to be replaced??

My current code is like below:

```
<RibbonToggleButton x:Name="_ribbon1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <RibbonToggleButton.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource boolCopyPaster}">
            <Binding ElementName="_copy" Path="IsSelected"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="_paste" Path="IsSelected"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </RibbonToggleButton.IsChecked>
</RibbonToggleButton>

<RibbonMenuButton x:Name="_selectorMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <RibbonGallery x:Name="_selector" Width="200">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Selectors">
            <RibbonGalleryItem x:Name="_item1">
                <Line Y1="7" Y2="7" X2="25" Stroke="Black"></Line>
            </RibbonGalleryItem>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
</RibbonMenuButton>
```

Comment: https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon try to check their old nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fluent.Ribbon/6.1.0.326

Comment: yup nice direction, but how do eliminate Ribbon without using any other resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 or later you can download the external `Ribbon` assemblies from Microsoft's official web site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877. This is the original version of the `Ribbon` control that later made it into the .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: But how do I use it on client PCs ? Every user needs to install it ?? Or I've to package up .msi with my executable's or any other work around ???

Comment: You just reference and include the downloaded DLLs in your output directory as usual.

Comment: You only need to download the assemblies to your development machine provided that you ship them as part of your application.